# Compare String date with today's date. Only compare month and day

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have string of date with format like this: 19930508. I want to use only 0508 from this string which is MMdd and than compare it with today's MMdd.
The code i am using is:

```
Date todaysDate = new Date();
String dateTest = "19930508";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd");
Date date = df.parse(dateTest);
String birthDate = df.format(date);

if(birthDate.equals(df.format(todaysDate))){do something}
```

The problem is the that birthdate formate is not working correctly neither todaysDate. 
Date date var print nothing and birthDate string print 0220 which makes no sense to me. 
Anyone with anyidea how can i work with this kind of formating and compare it with todaysdate ?

Comment: Yeah you should be using Calendar object,this is really the best library for date handling.

Comment: @juju no it definitily is not the best API for date handling, but until Java 8 it is the only integrated API

Comment: Calendar is long winded, especially if you have to include Timestamps, but it works.......just, provided you're only programming in one time zone.

Comment: `Date` and `Calendar` are definitely **not** the best lib for date handling: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api, http://www.jroller.com/cpurdy/entry/the_seven_habits_of_highly and https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/01/time/

Answer (score 5):

Using java.time from Java 8:

```
    MonthDay now = MonthDay.now();

    String dateTest = "19930508";
    DateTimeFormatter yearMonthDayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
    MonthDay birthDay = MonthDay.parse(dateTest, yearMonthDayFormatter);

    if (birthDay.equals(now)) {
        System.out.println("same MMdd");
    } else {
        System.out.println("different MMdd");
    }
```

Comment: Updated using MonthDay rather than LocalDate

Comment: This java.time is not available in java 7 ? this solutions seems workable to me.

Comment: If you're stuck with Java 7, you might want to use Joda Time (a library very similar to java.time in Java 8).

Comment: No, not available, so either upgrade to Java 8 or use joda-time as suggested. (Syntax is probalby almost identical).

Comment: @AbbasZahid Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Built by the same folks who built java.time.

Comment: From what I hear and read, you should prefer ThreeTen Backport over JodaTime (haven’t got experience with either myself, but I’m quite a fan of `java.time`).

Comment: @ViktorMellgren i did not able to find MonthDay with joda time, can you tell me the alternate of Monthday in joda time ?

Comment: JodaTime's `MonthDay`: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/MonthDay.html

Comment: @Hugo the lib of JodaTime i have in my project doesn't support this MonthDay functionality. I believe the lib is quite old

Comment: Indeed, `MonthDay` exists only in jodatime >= 2.0

Answer (score 1):

```
// works with java6
public class AnniversaryChecker {
    private final String dayInYear;

    public AnniversaryChecker() {
        this(new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd").format(new Date()));
    }

    // VisibleForTesting
    public AnniversaryChecker(String mmdd) {
        this.dayInYear = mmdd;
    }

    public boolean isAnniversary(String yyyyMMdd) {
        return yyyyMMdd.endsWith(dayInYear);
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI The troublesome old date-time classes such as SimpleDateFormat and Date are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: It’s probably the best you can do if you neither want to move to Java 8 nor want to depend on an external library (like ThreeTen Backport). It’s funnily backward, isn’t it? Not comparing the dates, but their string representations. Also you get no validation of the yyyyMMdd string; if by accident you got a completely irrelevant string, you wouldn’t notice, you’d just be told it isn’t your anniversary (of course validation can be added, but it will be extra).

Comment: I really don't want to use external library and java 8 as per project restrictions. i am trying to understand this example provided by @Frank and trying to see how can i validate it with todays date

Comment: @AbbasZahid If you have all those restrictions (can't use external libs and java < 8), you could update the question with it. This would prevent people from writing "incorrect" answers